# Using stack ghc as replacement of ghc

Tags: haskell-stack

Packages that are distributed without using stack or cabal usually have a set of implied dependencies. This sometimes mean that running ghc directly on said packages will not work without installing packages into ghcs global package database.

I would like to use `stack ghc` as a replacement for `ghc` to this end I have defined the following in my shells init file:

```
export PATH="`stack path --compiler-bin`:$PATH"
```

Now the command `ghc` will use stack's ghc - it does *not* however do the same as `stack ghc`. For one, it does not load the "snapshot" and "global-project" package database as can be seen with the following commands:

```
$ ghc -v
Glasgow Haskell Compiler, Version 8.0.1, stage 2 booted by GHC version 7.10.3
Using binary package database: ~/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-nopie-8.0.1/lib/ghc-8.0.1/package.conf.d/package.cache
...
$ stack ghc -- -v
Glasgow Haskell Compiler, Version 8.0.1, stage 2 booted by GHC version 7.10.3
Using binary package database: ~/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-nopie-8.0.1/lib/ghc-8.0.1/package.conf.d/package.cache
Using binary package database: ~/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux-nopie/lts-7.9/8.0.1/pkgdb/package.cache
Using binary package database: ~/.stack/global-project/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-nopie/lts-7.9/8.0.1/pkgdb/package.cache
...
```

Does anyone have guidance on how to achieve using `stack ghc` as a replacement for `ghc`.

The use-case I currently have is that I have been given a make-file that refers to `ghc` - but I do not have this command on my machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you execute the makefile within `stack exec`, it will set the GHC_PACKAGE_PATH environment variable.  It will also extend `PATH` appropriately.

Alternatively, to have this set in your shell you could do

```
export GHC_PACKAGE_PATH=`stack path --ghc-package-path`
```